# What specific coding languages does a developer need to know to make wordpress themes?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I understand you need to know the following languages:

- HTML/CSS
- JAVASCRIPT
- PHP

Is there any other languages I need to know in order to make a dynamic wordpress theme?

Comment: you barely even need to know those to make a dynamic wordpress theme

Comment: @mandrake You should try to make a Wordpress theme and learn as you go, if that's what you want to learn to do.

Comment: @Brad im learning javascript right now! that should help me learn php :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML/CSS

JAVASCRIPT

PHP

Those will cover everything you want to do with a wordpress theme.

The wordpress codex will also give you insight into the available wordpress PHP functions that you can use to make your theme work well with wordpress. I can't stress enough how important it is to use the codex.

http://codex.wordpress.org/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation

Comment: thanks! i thought those were the ones. if i could upvote you i would!

Comment: @mandrake No problem, just be sure to use native wordpress functions when you can (if you need to do something with wordpress, 8/10 times there's a function for it already). Also, you can mark my answer as accepted if you'd like.